# How to extract data from HTML tags using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.6

Can someone tell me how can I extract Project Summary from this using Beautifulsoup?

Here is my HTML file

```
<p><strong>Educational Qualification:</strong></p>

<blockquote>

<p>❖ B.Tech Computer Science from JNTU-Ananthapur in 2012.</p>

<p>❖ M.B.A Noble College Of Science and technology from JNTU-Ananthpur in 2013(Disc).</p>

<p><strong>Professional Experience:</strong></p>

<p>❖ Working as Software Engineer for YOUGOTAG Technologies Solutions Dec’15-Till date</p>

<p>❖ Working as Software Engineer for ARKSWAY TECHNOLOGIES PRIVATE LIMITED May’14-Nov’15</p>

<p><strong>Project Summary:</strong></p>

<p><strong><span class="underline">Project #6:</span></strong></p>

<p>Title : eGangaa Field Agent</p>

<p>Period : Aug’18 to Jant’19</p>

<p>Description : The eGangaa Field Agent app is a handy tool for field agents of suppliers</p>

<p><strong>Environment :</strong> android SDK, Java, SQLite, REST API, JSON, SVN and Git.</p>



</blockquote>
```

Its returning blank without any output. How can I extract Project summary from this?

Here is my code:

```
with open('E:/cvparser/abcd.html', encoding = 'utf-8') as report:

    raw = report.readlines()

    str = """""".join(raw)

    #print(str)

soup = BeautifulSoup(str, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('p:contains("Project Summary") ~ *:not(p:contains("Project Summary") ~ p, p:contains("Project Summary") ~ p ~ *)'):

    print(tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Comment: Could you please indicate the expected output

Comment: Expected Output:                                                                                                                      Working as Software Engineer for YOUGOTAG Technologies Solutions Dec’15-                                                                                             Till date

Working as Software Engineer for ARKSWAY TECHNOLOGIES PRIVATE LIMITED May’14-Nov’15 @QHarr

Comment: Please see edited answer based on that

Answer (score 0):

You can do the filtering with `:contains` and `:has` as shown below bs4 4.7.1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open('path', encoding = 'utf-8', mode = 'r') as report:

    raw = report.readlines()

    str = """""".join(raw)
soup = bs(str, 'html.parser')
experience ='\n'.join([i.text for i in soup.select('p:has(strong:contains("Professional Experience")) ~ p:not(p:has(strong:contains("Project Summary")), p:has(strong:contains("Project Summary")) ~ p)')])
print(experience)
```

Answer (score 0):

What can be done in this case @QHarr

```
<p><strong>WORK EXPERIENCE:</strong></p>

<p><strong>Dec- 2013 – Mar 2018</strong></p>

<blockquote>

<p><strong>Organization : XPIO Technologies Pvt Ltd Bangalore. </strong></p>

<p><strong>Position : Software Engineer </strong></p>

</blockquote>

<p><strong>Mar- 2018 – Till Date</strong></p>

<blockquote>

<p><strong>Organization : Indegene Pvt Ltd Bangalore. </strong></p>

<p><strong>Position : Software Engineer </strong></p>

</blockquote>
```

Expected output:

```
Dec- 2013 – Mar 2018
Organization : XPIO Technologies Pvt Ltd Bangalore. 
XPIO Technologies Pvt Ltd Bangalore. 
Mar- 2018 – Till Date
Organization : Indegene Pvt Ltd Bangalore.
Position : Software Engineer
```